# receive fatal error in multiple upload

Tags: php

This code is actually working i have no problem but when my leader ask me to make the upload multiple the problems begins, my leader want to have 2 upload button so that when the user click submit 2 files will be save in the server folder.

**indexaa.php**

```
<?php
$smp_id = (int) @$_GET['i'];
$i = $db->get_row("select * from sample where smp_id='$smp_id'");
?>

    <form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="smp_id" value="<? echo $smp_id ?>"/>
        <table class='generic'>
            <tr><td>Proposal Attachment</td><td><input type='file' name='file' value=''></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Proposal Attachment</td><td><input type='file' name='file1' value=''></td></tr>     
            <tr><td colspan='2'>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="JSPOPUP_close">
            <input type="button" value="Close" class="JSPOPUP_close">
            </td></tr>
        </table>

    </form>
```

this line of code`<tr><td>Proposal Attachment</td><td><input type='file' name='file1' value=''></td></tr>` ill just add it so that I will have 2 upload buttons. then in upload.php i add this line `$file1 = fs_upload($_FILES['file1']);` to support the `file1` and i add this `$sm_sql['presentation'] = $file1;` so that the `file1` name will save in my sample table, did i forgot something? *note: it is working when it is not multiple upload(1 file upload only)*

**upload.php**

```
<?
include("base_main.php");
$smp_id = (int) $_POST['smp_id'];

$file = fs_upload($_FILES['file']);
$file1 = fs_upload($_FILES['file1']);

$sm_sql['proposal'] = $file;
$sm_sql['presentation'] = $file1;

$insert = insertformat($sm_sql);
$query = $db->query("update sample set $insert where smp_id='$smp_id'");

if($query){
message_set("File uploaded: <a href='$fileserver_path/dex/$file'>$file</a>  <a href='$fileserver_path/dex/$file1'>$file1</a>");
goback();
}
?>
```

this is the

> error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class upload in
>   C:.....................\class.upload.php on line 363

Link of `class.upload.php` http://www.verot.net/download/class.upload.php/class.upload_0.25.txt

Comment: Copy the file once it has uploaded once! Unless you would like two different files, your question wasnt too clear! Anyway, check the `fs_upload()` function and make sure it is not redeclaring the upload class

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere you are including the file that contains `class upload` twice:

```
include 'class.upload.php';
```

Supposedly it's somewhere in the `fs_upload` function.

Only include the file *once* using `require_once` or `include_once` instead of `include`.